# Upload file using form-data body

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to upload a PNG file using an API which says:

> The request body accepts multipart/form-data with the key as uploadedFile.

Using Chrome postman plugin, I am able to upload the file using API, this is what I did:

```
Header: none
Body
  type: form-data
  key: uploadedFile
  Value: <file-location>
POST
```

This is the Python code that I have written:

```
login = requests.post(login_url, <other options>)
# above login is successful

upload_url = "Some_Value"
file_path = '/root/sample.png'
file = {'file': ('pngfile', open(file_path, 'rb'), 'image/png')}

body  = { 'uploadedFile':  file_path}

post_file = requests.post(upload_url, files=file, data=body,  cookies=login.cookies, verify=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
Bad Request[ errorCode:-18 ,message:Unsupported image file format. Please upload an image in GIF, JPEG or PNG format.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload the file under the `uploadedFile` name. Do not use that name with a path, *name the file itself that*:

```
upload_url = "Some_Value"
file_path = '/root/sample.png'
file = {'uploadedFile': ('pngfile', open(file_path, 'rb'), 'image/png')}

post_file = requests.post(upload_url, files=file, cookies=login.cookies, verify=False)
```

POSTMan does the same thing; it takes the file location, *loads the file data* and sends the file data under the name `uploadedFile`.

You get the error message because by using `uploadedFile` in the `data` section, you sent a `form-data` section with no mimetype and binary data that is just a local file path string, not PNG or other image data. The `file` section is probably entirely ignored, because that's not the name the server is looking for.